# Compare Data from 2 Worksheets in Excel 2011

Tags: excel, excel-2011, vba

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets of alphabetical business listings, one from this year and the other from last year. The 2012 listings have categories assigned to them, the 2013 ones don't.

I want to copy the categories from the 2012 listings to the 2013 listings that still exist. How would I go about doing this? I've done a lot of Googling about it and have come up empty as to how I would tackle this.

2012 Listings

```
Business Name     Category
Business A        Services       
Business B        Shopping
Business C        Automotive
```

New 2013 Listings

```
Business Name     Category
Business A        Services       
Business C        Automotive
New Business      ???
```

For the new businesses I need to manually decide what they fall under, but as it stands I don't even know which businesses need categories. There are a lot of other columns, but they don't really matter per say in this issue.

My experience with Excel is quite limited, so any hand holding you can provide will help. Thanks.

Comment: Trying using VLookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your 2012 listing is in Sheet1 and the header row starts in A1, with a similar setup for 2013 in Sheet2. Then the following lookup formula, beginning in cell B2 (or another column), of Sheet2 will bring over the categories:

```
  =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,0)
```

If there was no category assigned in 2012 to a business listed in 2013, this formula will return a N/A error value showing that you need to assign a category.

Comment: It did work, though when it started encountering listings that didn't line up with 2012 things went off the rails. So it worked for the first 4 listings, then there was a business from 2012 that was no longer there, so the cell comparison no longer worked, as cell A6 was no longer the same as cell A6 in 2013. I basically need to check against all listings in column A to see if it existed the previous year, then find if it had the category. Is that possible?

Comment: I noticed a small error in the formula (first cell reference should be A2 instead of A1). You need to make sure you adjusted the range reference $A$2:$B$6 to the actual number of data rows in Sheet1 ($A$2:$B$100, for example). The $ signs are important, too: they prevents the lookup range from shifting when you copy the formula down.

Comment: Okay, I modified the formula to =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$900,2,0) and now it seems to be just returning the category for the first listing and nothing else.

Comment: When you copy it down to the bottom of the data range, it just keeps returning the same value?

Comment: Weird, I tried it at work and it was just repeating the value, but reloaded it at home and it worked. I'll take it. Thanks so much for your help. I marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Perhaps automatic recalculation was turned off at work. Glad to be of help.